# tomcat kerberos authentication + ldap authorization

Tags: tomcat, ldap, kerberos

We use LDAP to authenticate **and** authorize users on a tomcat server, but now need to remove the passwords from LDAP and switch over to kerberos authentication.

Now we would like to **authenticate** the users **using kerberos** (works already fine) and on success, **retrieve** the assigned **roles** for the logged in user from the **LDAP** DB.

My naive hope would be to use e.g. a simple self made realm and/or WSDLs security-constrain/-roles mechanisms to a) authenticate using the JAAS realm and on success b) pass over to the JNDI realm to retrieve the roles from the LDAP DB for the authenticated user.

I could find many fragments for some of the needed steps (retrieve roles, simple home made realms, …), but no easy to follow example and I'm still not sure if this approach is appropriate at all (especially since I'm pretty new to this topic(s)!).

Comment: What is you Tomcat version? Are you on Active Directory? I have fully written code for that. `SpnegoAuthenticator` and `ActiveDirectoryRealm`. I do plan to release that as open source on sf.net.

Comment: Michael-O: Tomcat 7.0.26, I'm not using Active Directory but openldap (2.4.28)  I guess one might be able to adjust your code to also work with OpenLDAP instead of Active Directory - right? Any help code snippet would be welcome!

Comment: The SpnegoAuthenticator will be the same but the user serch and group retrieval must be changed. Does your OpenLDAP installation support GSS-API SASL mech?

Comment: yes should at least be possible to add on easily!

Comment: Great, please contact me through [SF.net](http://sourceforge.net/users/michael-o).

Answer (score 0):

Just to round up this thread. Found a nice solution named **ldaptive** (see http://www.ldaptive.org/). Here I can exactly specify and kerberos login module (com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule) and LDAP for authorisation (org.ldaptive.jaas.LdapRoleAuthorizationModule). We are now running with this module since a long time and it simply works flawlessly!